# How to change global style of document in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice

I am a web developer and I want to style my libreoffice document like CSS.

I want to have a 1.5 line height everywhere except for list.

All the ul with 1.5 line (default) but the li in single line.

Is there a way to customize styling like that for all my future documents ?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if you can create a separate style for libreoffice documents... But you can create a Template document for your future needs. Check out this link:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/94734/what-is-the-templates-folder-in-the-home-directory-for

This is good for creating documents for example inventory list, performance tracker etc .. but can be tuned to have some basic styling changes like change of margin size, general line hight etc.